# How can I acces the value of a function argument outside of the function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters, arguments

I need to access the value of a certain function argument outside of it.
I have a function of this type:

```
def Function(n=10)
    ...
```

Then I call the function, sometimes with a n value different than its default value, for example:

```
Function(5)
```

I would like to access that n value and put it in a variable x. I tried to use inspect module and did this:

```
x = inspect.getfullargspec(Function)
```

and this shows me the default value (10) and I guess I could somehow extract it, but if the n value changes from default (for example 5), I don't find a place where it's written with this inspect function. It only gives me the argument name "n", but not its value. How can I do that?

Comment: That's a local variable. It doesn't exist outside of the function, and the local value might change every time the function is called. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking...

Comment: You can just return the value inside the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is assign its value to another variable, which is global

```
def Function(n=10):
    global n1
    n1=n
```

Now you can use n1 outside the function also.